# manage.py not generated

Tags: python, django

I just installed django  after i run 
`django-admin.py startproject test2`

```
  BOX@BOXLinux:~/django/test2/test2$ ls
  __init__.py  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py
```

There is no file called manage.py ? is my mistake or a bug in django

Comment: which version of django?

Comment: is it in the dir above the one you just listed?

Comment: 1.4 alpha 1 its seem i download the in correct version but the i taken from official installation guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using the development version, for some reason. In that version, the structure has changed a bit so that manage.py is in the directory above.

You should really be using version 1.3, until 1.4 is released.

Comment: i download Django-1.3.1 but it still give 1.4 alpha 1